# .Net Oracle 11G - Connection Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out

Tags: c#, oracle

I've facing the following issue when I connect with Oracle11G. When I connect with Oracle10G it work fine.

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out

```
   builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
   (
   options =>
   options.UseOracle(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("OracleDb")) );
```

My Connection String is as follows.

```
"OracleDb": "User Id=PGCJIRA; Password=JIRA;Data Source=10.12.4.29:1521/orcl;Validate Connection=true",

Using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise .Net 6.0
Nuget Package : Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.100
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess : 21.10.0
Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore : 7.21.9
```

Tried following solution but failed:

1. Validate Connection=true in Connection String
2. Change Connection String "User Id=JIRA; Password=JIRA;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.12.4.29)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))",
3. Connection  Max Pool Size=5
4. Concection Timeout : 240

Following Exception

```
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
Exception thrown: 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
An exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll but was not handled in user code
External component has thrown an exception.
```

Comment: Oracle is very sensitive to version of database and version of driver used to connect to the database.  Make sure you are using correct version.  See : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/new-dotnet-features.html#category-odp

Comment: Also consider this may not be a client configuration problem as much as a networking problem: could there be a firewall or other form of anti-virus or malware protection software blocking the connection? That can also show up as a timeout, depending on how the connection is blocked.